# Angular library compilation with file changes issue

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-library

I have a library on angular 12 which when served, watches for changes and automatically triggers the build again. My script for automatically building the library is:
`ng build library --watch`.

The issue is after building successfully, the automatic build triggers every minute even when no changes are made to any file.

[image: Build info]

My `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "test-library",
    "version": "1.0.0-1",
    "scripts": {
        "ver": "genversion --es6 --semi ./libs/ui/src/lib/version-number/version-number.model.ts",
        "ng": "ng",
        "serve": "ng build library --watch",
        "build": "ng build library --configuration production",
        "npm-publish": "node cleanPackage.js && npm publish dist"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
        "core-js": "^3.16.2",
        "date-fns": "2.23.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
        "@angular/animations": "^12.2.5",
        "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.5",
        "@angular/common": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/core": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/material": "^12.2.5",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/router": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/service-worker": "~12.2.5",
        "@ngrx/effects": "12.4.0",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "12.4.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "12.4.0",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "12.4.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/animations": "^12.2.5",
        "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.5",
        "@angular/cli": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/common": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/core": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/language-service": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/material": "^12.2.5",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/router": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/service-worker": "~12.2.5",
        "@angularclass/hmr": "^3.0.0",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
        "@ks89/angular-modal-gallery": "^7.2.5",
        "@ngrx/effects": "12.4.0",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "12.4.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "12.4.0",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "12.4.0",
        "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
        "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.13",
        "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
        "@types/jest": "25.1.4",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "angular-cc-library": "^2.1.2",
        "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^6.0.1",
        "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "core-js": "^3.16.2",
        "cypress": "^5.1.0",
        "date-fns": "2.23.0",
        "dotenv": "6.2.0",
        "edit-json-file": "^1.6.0",
        "genversion": "^2.2.1",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jest": "^27.0.0",
        "jest-preset-angular": "9.0.6",
        "lodash.isequal": "4.5.0",
        "mousetrap": "^1.6.5",
        "ng-packagr": "^12.2.1",
        "ng-samurai": "^2.0.6",
        "ng2-charts": "^2.2.3",
        "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
        "prettier": "^2.0.4",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
        "signature_pad": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
        "ts-jest": "~27.0.5",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~4.3.5",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    }
}
```

My `angular.json`:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "projects": {
        "web": {
            "projectType": "library",
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "fin",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.lib.json",
                        "project": "ng-package.json"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js"
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.lib.json",
                            "tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "web",
    "cli": {
        "defaultCollection": "@nrwl/angular",
        "analytics": false
    },
    "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:application": {
            "unitTestRunner": "jest",
            "e2eTestRunner": "cypress"
        },
        "@nrwl/angular:library": {
            "unitTestRunner": "jest"
        },
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
            "styleext": "scss"
        }
    }
}
```

I have projects that use this library and when the library builds every minute it triggers a build on the project as well making it to reload. This is really tough especially when debugging things on the project. I don't know what's the issue here and any help is appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: It also recompiles when you do `Ctrl` + `S` without any file changes. Do you maybe have a plugin that autosaves files?

Comment: It recompiles automatically even without clicking `Ctrl` + `S`. I'm relying on angular's `--watch` flag to auto recompile and not using any plugins. I've added the List of libraries I'm using in my query. If something raises a red flag in that list or my angular.json configuration or if you need more info, do let me know.